# Is it possible to recover Tomboy Notes from Ubuntu One, now that the sync feature is gone?

Tags: sync, tomboy

Recently, Ubuntu One dropped its Tomboy Notes sync feature. Is there any way to recover the notes that I've synced with Ubuntu One, now that the sync feature is gone? I currently don't have the notes synced with any of my computers, but I don't want to lose all the notes that I've synced over the last few years.
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/ubuntu-one-notes-feature-written-off

Comment: I don't want to lose all the notes, stories, ideas, etc. that I've written over the past couple of years - is there any way to recover the previously-synced notes now?

Comment: I'm trying to access my notes now, but the page wasn't found, apparently.  https://one.ubuntu.com/notes

Answer (score 1):

According to [the article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/ubuntu-one-notes-feature-written-off):

> The ‘notes’ feature of the Ubuntu One web interface is to be removed.
>
> The feature removal will only impact on the Ubuntu One website itself. Note sync to Ubuntu One through Tomboy or similar applications ***will not be affected***.

So it appears you can keep using the feature from Tomboy.

That said, it's a good idea to keep external backups of any important material you place on cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

It's still possible to synchronize notes with the Ubuntu One server - the feature hasn't yet been dropped completely. I managed to download my notes using the instructions here: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-setup-tomboy-notes-to-sync-with-ubuntu-one/