# Sync Tomboy Notes

Tags: sync, notes

I have notes synced via Tomboy Web.

Now I reinstalled my system and I am trying to setup but it requires me to connect to a Server.

[image]

What is the server's name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the server used to be Ubuntu One, but that feature [has been removed](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/ubuntu-one-announce-tomboy-note-sync-to-stop-working-late-february). You can use your own server if you have access to one. Another option is to sync Tomboy with a local folder which in turn syncs with Ubuntu One (or Dropbox, or any other cloud service).

Comment: No, there were two separate options. Ubuntu One and tomboy Web. I always used Tomboy Web. And now there is a Tomboy Web option, but no server. Hm, if it was Ubuntu One server in Tomboy Web option then my Notes would not sync.

Comment: Well then it's your own server or one you have direct access to and can upload your notes to. I can't really tell you what that server is then. How were you syncing your notes before exactly?

Comment: Not sure, I just know I used Tomboy Web, and some default value for  server name. Now my notes are probably on that server and I cant access them :)

Comment: I think that was Ubuntu One (example [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HeoAt.png), [2](http://charlesmccolm.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/tomboy.jpg), [3](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_HDxiDiO4YKI/S_KfLH-C9OI/AAAAAAAAAIc/2jN2xrjKcqs/s1600/Selection_005.png), [4](http://www.eweek.com/imagesvr_ce/eweek/images/stories/slideshows/ubuntu_9_10_beta/ubuntu10.jpg), and [5](http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/ubuntu/bilder/tomboy_sync.png)). So your notes would probably be on there. You should still be able to access them but you can't sync anymore.

Comment: Yes, yes, probably. The page is 404 now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Did you manage to get your notes back? I'm pretty sure they're still on your account. Just log in to one.ubuntu.com and they should be there.

Comment: No, they are not there.

Comment: That's disappointing. Can [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/239403/is-it-possible-to-recover-tomboy-notes-from-ubuntu-one-now-that-the-sync-featur?rq=1) help at all? You can try to revive the question to see if anyone knows how to recover them.

Comment: No problem, I will manage without them. I will use google keep from now on. Looks like Ubuntu services are not something you can rely on. If someone knows, I'm sure he will share solution here. Thanks again.